# read file through pipeline

Tags: shell-script, pipe

I have written an example code for reading the content of a file maitaining the end of line format using hack from the internet. I have called the shell file "pipeTesting" and the text file to display "textExample". "pipeTesting" works if I call the file as an argument of the shell script.

However, there are cases when files are retrieved via pipelines; if I provide the text to pipeTesting using a `cat` command, there are no arguments at all since `echo $@` does not print anything. To note that I had to use `-p /dev/stdin` to create a case for pipeline usage and one for argument usage.

Is there a way to display the content of the file maitaining the end of the line in case of a pipeline?

thank you.

The code looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then
    echo $@
else
    while read
    do
        echo $REPLY
    done < $1
fi
exit 0
```

Its application is:

```
$ cat textExample.txt
Much I marvelled this ungainly fowl to hear discourse so plainly,
Though its answer little meaning- little relevancy bore;
For we cannot help agreeing that no living human being
Ever yet was blessed with seeing bird above his chamber door-
Bird or beast upon the sculptured bust above his chamber door,
With such name as "Nevermore."
$ pipeTester textExample.txt 
Much I marvelled this ungainly fowl to hear discourse so plainly,
Though its answer little meaning- little relevancy bore;
For we cannot help agreeing that no living human being
Ever yet was blessed with seeing bird above his chamber door-
Bird or beast upon the sculptured bust above his chamber door,
With such name as "Nevermore."
$ cat textExample.txt | pipeTester 
_
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/sh

infile=${1--}

cat "$infile"
```

That is, set the `infile` variable to the name of the first argument, but if that's not available, set it to `-`.  `cat` with `-` as input file name will read from standard input (i.e. from a pipe or a redirection).

---

Shorter:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat -- "${1--}"
```

or, as Stéphane points out,

```
cat -- "$@"
```

which would additionally allow you to give multiple filenames on the command line.

---

Shorter still:

```
alias PipeTester=cat
```

What you're doing is more or less a reimplementation of `cat`. Your `PipeTester` script may in fact be replaced by `cat` and the above does that by means of an alias.

Comment: or `cat -- ${1+"$1"}` or `cat -- "$@"` (also `exec cat -- "$@"` for those sh implementations that don't do the optimisation by themselves).